# remove substring, if small part of that substring matches with selector

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a record in the column named `websites` with the following text:

```
["https://twitter.com/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]
```

I would like to delete all the websites that contain `youtube.com` and `twitter.com`, namely `"https://twitter.com/use312"` and `"https://youtube.com/bel"`
, but keep all other substrings (`"http://keepthiswebsite"`)

So the result of mysql statement on the record above should be `["http://keepthiswebsite"]`.

I would really like to do this with mysql, without python or some other scripting language. How can I do this?

Comment: how many urls are in one column ?

Comment: not sure. from zero to 10

Comment: First, normalise the database. Then it will be simple.

Comment: Not sure what that means. will google. Any other direct way?

Comment: No. Normalisation is the right practise dude.

Comment: REPLACE with FIND_IN_SET and a WHERE clause if you want to get rid of those in the row. However, the question's unclear. If you want to "delete" the row, then DELETE from the table with LIKE or FIND_IN_SET ought to work.

Comment: Don't want to delete row, but just part of string in it.

Comment: then use REPLACE. I'd consider redoing that db if you're not too far into it though.

Comment: @Fred-ii- `FIND_IN_SET()` or `REPLACE()` both search only for fixed strings, not for patterns. I assume the URLs contain a variety of path components.

Comment: @sanjihan, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad/3653574#3653574

Comment: @sanjihan short answer is that it's easier to write a script in Python or any other language, this is really not a good task to do in SQL.

Comment: @BillKarwin Thanks Bill. Yeah, a regex would work beautifully here. But storing JSON like that, not a good idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you looking for, but it is not very nice and you must hast a unique id on each row.

```
SELECT url ,CONCAT('[', result_url,']') as result_url
FROM (
SELECT u.url,
@r:= TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(url,',,,,,,,,,,'), ',', ids.id)),',',1)),'[',''),']','')),
@r:= IF(@r = '' , NULL, @r),
@r:= IF(INSTR( @r ,'youtube.com') > 0 , NULL, @r) ,
@r:= IF(INSTR( @r ,'twitter.com') > 0 , NULL, @r) ,
-- Here you can add your own removes. only duplicate last line
GROUP_CONCAT( @r SEPARATOR ', ' )  as result_url
FROM (
SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 ) as ids
CROSS JOIN `urlstable` u
CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @r:='') as init
GROUP BY u.id
ORDER BY u.id,ids.id
) as remove;
```

**sample**

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM urlstable;
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | url                                                                                  |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | ["https://twitter.com/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  |
|  2 | ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"] |
|  3 | ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "https://google.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  |
|  4 | ["https://mydomain.de/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  |
+----+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> SELECT url ,CONCAT('[', result_url,']') as result_url
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT u.url,
    -> @r:= TRIM(BOTH ' ' FROM REPLACE(REPLACE(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(REVERSE(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(url,',,,,,,,,,,'), ',', ids.id)),',',1)),'[',''),']','')),
    -> @r:= IF(@r = '' , NULL, @r),
    -> @r:= IF(INSTR( @r ,'youtube.com') > 0 , NULL, @r) ,
    -> @r:= IF(INSTR( @r ,'twitter.com') > 0 , NULL, @r) ,
    -> -- Here you can add your own removes. only duplicate last line
    -> GROUP_CONCAT( @r SEPARATOR ', ' )  as result_url
    -> FROM (
    -> SELECT 1 as id UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5
    ->  UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9 UNION ALL SELECT 10 ) as ids
    -> CROSS JOIN `urlstable` u
    -> CROSS JOIN ( SELECT @r:='') as init
    -> GROUP BY u.id
    -> ORDER BY u.id,ids.id
    -> ) as remove;
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| url                                                                                  | result_url                                                                          |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ["https://twitter.com/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  | ["http://keepthiswebsite"]                                                          |
| ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"] | ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "http://keepthiswebsite"]                           |
| ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "https://google.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  | ["https://twitterr.com/use312", "https://google.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"] |
| ["https://mydomain.de/use312", "https://youtube.com/bel", "http://keepthiswebsite"]  | ["https://mydomain.de/use312", "http://keepthiswebsite"]                            |
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
4 rows in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Woaw, thank you! It really is ugly :D

Comment: @sanjihan - if you have more urls in the field you must extend the **,,,,,,,,,** in the concat and extent the union. in the moment its only works for max 10 urls